# PHP mySQL Update page

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I'm trying to make a simple product page (no login or anything like that) in php and mysql.
So far, everything shows up on my products page fine, I can delete/add just fine from my admin page. From there I'm trying to figure out how to create an edit function.
So I made a form that populates from the mysql table based on the productid for convenience (edit2.php?id=X) which then posts to edit.php and hopefully updates the database.
So far, reusing the old code isn't working, somehow I was hoping it would be that simple.

This is my add product (which works) :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['hp']) && empty($_POST['hp'])) {
    if(
isset($_SESSION['token']) &&
$_SESSION['token'] == $_POST['token']
) {
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'test_admin', 'test');
        mysql_select_db('test_product');
        $data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
        $query = "
            INSERT INTO products (
                product_name, price, description, image
            ) VALUES (
                '{$data['product_name']}',
                '{$data['price']}',
                '{$data['description']}',
                '{$data['image']}'
            )
        ";
        if(mysql_query($query)) {
            echo '<p>Your information was successfully saved.</p>';
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
        } else {
            echo '<p>There was an error storing your data, please try again later.</p>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<p>Your data has already been saved.</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p>Error.<br />Please try again later.</p>';
}
?>
```

This is my update (which just throws out a syntax error or 'error storing your data' :

```
<?php

        mysql_connect('localhost', 'test_admin', 'test');
        mysql_select_db('lbriedis_product');


        $data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
        $query = "UPDATE products WHERE id = ".$pageid." (
                product_name, price, description, image
            ) VALUES (
                '{$data['product_name']}',
                '{$data['price']}',
                '{$data['description']}',
                '{$data['image']}'
            )
        ";
        if(mysql_query($query)) {
            echo '<p>Your information was successfully saved.</p>';
            unset($_SESSION['token']);
        } else {
            echo '<p>There was an error storing your data, please try again    later.</p>';
            echo mysql_error(); //Used for development and testing only
        }
?>
```

I get session errors when I attempt to use session validation probably because I start a session on my admin page (add product form is on admin.php, edit and delete are links) ?
Nevertheless, I removed the session checks for the moment as I'm struggling more so with the update part.

Also I'm not sure of the best way to pass $pageid to the update query for 'update where id = $pageid. I have a hidden field with the value (see edit form), how do I reference this correctly?

Edit form (values display correctly so where id = $pageid is working here:

```
<?php
        $dol = "$";
        $pageid = (int)$_GET['id']; 
        mysql_connect('localhost', 'lbriedis_admin', 'xxxxxx123');
        mysql_select_db('lbriedis_product');
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE id = ".$pageid."");
    if($result){
  $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}


    ?>

<form id="inputForm" method="post" action="edit.php">


    <fieldset>

   <label>Pool name:</label>
 <?php
   echo '<input type="text" name="product_name" value="'.$data['pool_name'].'" />';
     ?> 

    <label>Price:</label> <br>
     <?php
   echo '$&nbsp;<input type="text" name="price" value="'.$data['price'].'" />';
    ?>  <br />
    <label>Description:</label>
      <?php
   echo '<textarea name="description">'.$data['description'].'</textarea>';
    ?>

 <label>Image:</label></label>
  <?php
   echo '<input type="text" name="image" value="'.$data['image'].'" />';
    ?>  
    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>" />
     <input type="text" id="hp" name="hp" />
     <?php
   echo '$&nbsp;<input type="hidden" name="$pageid" value="'.$pageid.'" />';
    ?>  

    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" />

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your [update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) query have incorrect **sintax**

```
    $query = "UPDATE products WHERE id = ".$pageid." (
            product_name, price, description, image
        ) VALUES (
            '{$data['product_name']}',
            '{$data['price']}',
            '{$data['description']}',
            '{$data['image']}'
        )
```

correct sintax should be

```
    $query="UPDATE products SET
            product_name = '".$data['product_name']."', 
            price ='".$data['price']."',
            description = '".$data['description']."',
            image = '".$data['image']."'
            WHERE id = '".$pageid."'
```

Comment: where do you get $pageid from?

Comment: Are you asking me? It's in the original script `$pageid = (int)$_GET['id']; `

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
name="$pageid"
```

to

```
name="pageid"
```

and access it like this

```
$data = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
$query = "UPDATE products WHERE id = {$data['pageid']} (
```

the problem was `$pageid` was not accessible in `edit.php`. And you have assigned `$pageid` to `name` attribute , which will be different fot each product.

Change the query to this

```
$query="UPDATE products SET
        product_name = '{$data['product_name']}', 
        price ='{$data['price']}',
        description = '{$data['description']}',
        image = '{$data['image']}'
        WHERE id = '{$data['pageid']}'
```

Comment: Cheers. The id comes through, but the update is still not working though:
There was an error storing your data, please try again later.
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE id = 21 ( product_name, price, description, image ) VALUES ( 'test' at line 1

Comment: @LukeBriedis Check the query and let me know if there is any error...:)

Comment: Cheers, works. Any idea on how to solve the session_start problem (as I have the add form on admin.php, and clicking on the edit.php?id= link seems to be taking that first session with it so right now I can't get the session going with my edit page :(

Comment: write `session_start();` at top of each page. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Cheers. I didn't realise I wasn't just starting a session I was also making a new token for no reason. Haha :(

Answer (score 0):

replace your update query with the below:-

```
$query = "UPDATE products 
  set product_name=$data['product_name'],
      price = $data['price'],
      description = $data['description'] ,
      image = $data['image']
      where id =". $pageid ;
```